# Why np.where, with a condition, does not work with only one row in a dataframe if condition not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parsing, split

Here is an example:

```
cars2 = {'Brand': ['Hon*da\nCivic', 'BM*AMT*B6*W'],'Price': [22000, 55000]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(cars2, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])


df2['Allowed_Amount'] = np.where(
                df2['Brand'].apply(lambda x: x.count("AMT" + "*" + "B6") > 0),
                df2['Brand'].str.split("AMT" + "*").str[1].str.split("B6").str[1].str[1:].str.split('\n').str[0], 0.00)
```

Output:

```
           Brand  Price Allowed_Amount
0  Hon*da\nCivic  22000              0
1    BM*AMT*B6*W  55000              W
```

Which is exactly what I need.

However, if the df contains only one row, which does not satisfy the condition, I get an error:

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Hon*da\nCivic'],'Price': [22000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

df['Allowed_Amount'] = np.where(
                    df['Brand'].apply(lambda x: x.count("AMT" + "*" + "B6") > 0),
                    df['Brand'].str.split("AMT" + "*").str[1].str.split("B6").str[1].str[1:].str.split('\n').str[0], 0.00)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

What I need:

```
           Brand  Price Allowed_Amount
0  Hon*da\nCivic  22000              0
```

Why doesn't it exit when the condition is not met? How to make this code work with one row as well?

Comment: IIUC you could use `df2['Allowed_Amount']=df2['Brand'].str.extract(r".*AMT\*B6\*(.*)").fillna(0)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that *df['Brand'].str.split("AMT" + "*")* in the
"negative" case returns a list of size **1** (the whole source string in a
**single** element).

In this case *.str[1]* (following the previous code) returns *None* and
"following" methods in your code can not be called on it.

But in *Pandas* the actual exception is raised **only** if the above case
occurs for **each** source element, just like in the case of *df*.

I also think that such a long sequence of *str.split*, *str* and index
selections is difficult to read.

Try another approach based on *extract* with a regex:

```
df['Allowed_Amount'] = df['Brand'].str.extract(r'AMT\*.*?B6.(.*)').fillna(0)
```

Details of the regex:

- `AMT\*` - Match `AMT` and an asterisk.
- `.*?` - Match any number of characters, as little as possible (chars
  between "AMT*" and "B6", if any). Maybe you can drop this fragment
  from the regex.
- `B6` - Represent themselves.
- `.` - Match any single char (a counterpart of `[1:]` in your code).
- `(.*)` - Match text up to a newline (excluding, as the dot does not match
  the newline) or to the end of string, as a **capturing group**, so this
  is just the extracted content.

If the above regex doesn't match, *NaN* is returned for this row.

These *NaN* values are then replaced with **0**, due to call to *fillna(0)*
afterwards.

Try the same on *df2*.

So this way you will achieve your desired result with shorter and more readable code.

Of course, it requires some knowledge of *regular expressions* but it is
definitely worth to take some time to learn them.

## Edit following the question

To replace the literal star it the regex with a given delimiter,
you can define the following function, generating the content
for the new column:

```
def myExtract(df, delimiter='*'):
    pat = rf'AMT\{delimiter}B6.(.*)'
    return df['Brand'].str.extract(pat).fillna(0)
```

As you can see:

- the *delimiter* is incorporated into the regex using *f-string*
  feature (can co-exist with *r-string*),
- it must be preceded with a backslash, to treat it **literally**
  (not as a special regex char).

And to generate the new colum, just call this function, passing at
least the source DataFrame (and optionally the right delimiter):

```
df['Allowed_Amount'] = myExtract(df); df
```

The same for *df2*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have another question: in the actual code the star is a delimiter, so it varies. In this case, i have it as delimiter = "*". How can i incorporate that in your code? I could also write another variable: my_string = "AMT"+delimiter+"B6", but how do i put it in your code?